# Visual Basic: reference label control from variable derived from checkbox control

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I'm writing a simple Windows Form app in VB using VS Community 2017.

I have 64 checkboxes with 64 associated labels, named chk1 / lbl1 up to chk64 / lbl64. When a checkbox is checked, I want to extract a character from a string and show the answer in the label: e.g. if chk12 is checked, I want lbl12 to be enabled and the text to display the 12th character of the string.

To save writing 64 separate handlers I'm trying to do it in one. I can extract the checked number (e.g. 12) OK and write it to a string, but when I try to manipulate the label control I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

The code I've come up with so far (largely from searching in here) is:

```
Private Sub CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
  Handles chk1.CheckedChanged, chk2.CheckedChanged 'etc. to 64

    ' wanted behaviour
    'If chk1.Checked Then
    '    lbl1.Enabled = True
    '    lbl1.Text = GetChar(userString, 1)
    'End If
    'If chk2Checked Then
    '    lbl2.Enabled = True
    '    lbl2.Text = GetChar(userString, 2)
    'End If
    ' etc. (to 64)

    Dim resultsLabel As String
    Dim userCheckedBox As Integer

    userCheckedBox = CInt(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Text)
    resultsLabel = "lbl" & DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Text

    Me.Controls(resultsLabel).Enabled = True
    Me.Controls(resultsLabel).Text = GetChar(userString, userCheckedBox)

End Sub
```

I'd be very grateful if someone can nudge me over the line with this. Many thanks!

Comment: resultsLabel = "lbl" & DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Name.SubString(3)

Comment: What is supposed to be the Text of a CheckBox? What if you don't have set that property to a number from 1 to 64 and then you try to build the name of the label with that invalid text?

Comment: Steve, the checkbox text is 1 for chk1, 2 for chk2, etc. These are set by default in my form.

Comment: Then I suggest you to use the debugger and check step by step what values are assigned to the variable inside the code above. Something is not as you think.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Both your and my resultsLabel lines work fine. It's the last two lines (Me.Controls...) that throw up the errors.

Comment: The `Text` in the `CheckBox` is set to the checkbox's name by default, which would be `"chk1"`, not `"1"`. Most probably the value of `resultsLabel` does not match the real label names.

Comment: Steve, the debugger shows that userCheckedBox is returning an integer and resultsLabel a string. For chkbox 1 this is "1" and "lbl1" respectively, which is what I was expecting. (For chk2 it's 2 (integer) and lbl2 (string).)

Comment: Then split this line _Me.Controls(resultsLabel).Enabled = True_ in two. _Dim lbl = DirectCast(Me.Control(resultsLabel), Label))_ and check if the expected label has been found in the collection, if yes probably the error is in GetChar

Comment: Do you mean one line with  Dim lbl = DirectCast(Me.Controls(resultsLabel), Label) and the next with lbl.Enabled = True ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Then with the debugger check if the variable lbl is nothing. If yes this means that you don't have a label with that Name property in you controls collection

Comment: Ah yes, the label is nothing.

Comment: Well this explains the exception now (Nothing.Enabled = true will crash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the old trick to use the Tag property of your checkboxes.
You can set the Tag property to the matching label name at design time using the WinForms Designer. So in the chk1.Tag property you will have the "lbl1" string assigned and so on for all the 64 checkboxes.
At this point your code in the event handler is simply

```
Dim chk = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
if chk IsNot Nothing Then
    Me.Controls(chk.Tag.ToString()).Enabled = True
    Me.Controls(chk.Tag.ToString()).Text = GetChar(userString, CInt(chk.Text))
End If
```

Comment: I can see how this would work if I was just manipulating the checkbox, but can't see how it will write to the label?

Comment: The code reads the full name of the label from the statically stored value in the Tag property. It will write the return value of GetChar to the label identified by the chk.Tag property.

Comment: Brilliant, I can see this is going to solve my problem! Still getting an object error, but e.g. "lbl1" is now passing correctly to chk.Tag

Comment: As found above it seems that you don't have a label with the property Name set to lbl1, the default is _label1_ etc...

Comment: Yes, I think some simplification is called for as it's now obvious I've been over-complicating things. Thanks for the pointers, Steve.